# Event driven functionality of Node

Tags: node.js

It has been said that Node is an event driven language.EX:

```
http.get('www.google.com', (response) => {
let data = ''

response.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunkenter code here
})

response.on('end', () => {
    console.log(data)
})

})
```

Here, a request has been forwarded to www.google.com and we set up event listeners to listen for the 'data' and 'end' events so as the request data comes in, we concatenate all the data together and log it once the request ends. The flow of the program here is determined by events.

So, My question is that, can we do same/similar things in any other language(framework)? Can this thing be only done in Node?

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

Any language can do this, but Node is currently considered the best due to its enormous package library.

Other cleaner languages such as Scala and C# also include Promises/Futures by default. Golang has channels, Python has async/await, and Ruby/Lua/Java also offer promises or promise-like functionality in the form of external packages.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that, can we do same/similar things in any other language (framework)?

Any language can implement events and have some operations that use events.  You can even do it in C or assembly language if you want.  But (see discussion below), node.js is deeply, deeply architected to be event driven (at the lowest level) which is not generally true of other languages.  That does make a difference.

> Can this thing be only done in Node?

No.  Levels of event notification can be done in any language.

But, node.js is fundamentally a single-threaded, event driven architecture and internally runs off an event queue so lots of things only work as event driven such as timers, network I/O, asynchronous file I/O.  The internal event queue is fundamental to the architecture of how node.js handles multiple asynchronous operations in flight at the same time.

For example, all network I/O is asynchronous and non-blocking and the ONLY way you can get network data is via callbacks which are internally triggered via the event queue.

---

One thing to keep in mind is that the single-threaded, event driven architecture of node.js is not exactly the same thing as some code that might decide to use the `EventEmitter` style event-driven notification system.  The internal architecture is pretty fundamental to the node.js design and it defines node.js non-blocking I/O architecture and affects how multiple asynchronous operations in node.js are run, when they run and what types of synchronization exists between multiple asynchronous operations in flight at the same time and how you code that.  This is very fundamental to node.js and I am not aware of another mainstream language that has this same internal design.  So, some of this is specific to node.js.

Creating some code that uses an `EventEmitter` style object to notify listeners of various events that are occurring is a capability that pretty much any language can add on top of their existing design (including node.js).  For example, you could create an EventEmitter style object in C that encapsulates a system timer and use events to notify listeners of timer events.  That's somewhat analogous to the publish/subscribe model which can be implemented on top of any language.